# Convert a python3 script in an executable with cx_Freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, cx-freeze

I'm recently made this chat app in python3 and I would like to convert my script in an executable, I made some research and I found and chose cx_Freeze because is multi-platform and I'm currently working with windows 10. I made this script to make the conversion but when I run it nothing happens. If someone could help me out here it will be great thanks!!!

```
import cx_Freeze
import sys


base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"

executables = [cx_Freeze.Executable("/mis programas/chat/aplicacion1.1.py", base=base, icon="/mis programas/iconos/3.png")]

cx_Freeze.setup(
    name = "PyChaT",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter"], "include_files":["/mis programas/iconos/3.png"]}},
    version = "1",
    description = "Source of communication",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: Try running through an open terminal to see what error is produced.

Comment: @Simon I´m using idle to run the code and see the errors but the script runs and it doesn´t show any errors, I don't know what I´m doing wrong.

Comment: Yes your code may not contain errors but your final exectables will.  Try running it through terminal (Terminal on Linux and Mac, cmd on Windows) and not the IDLE and you should see some form of message.

Comment: @Simon, I follow your advice, I run the script in the cmd console and this is the message:                                                                            `usage: executable.py [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
   or: executable.py --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
   or: executable.py --help-commands
   or: executable.py cmd --help

error: no commands supplied
`

Comment: @Simon I did it and now it creates the .exe file with a .dll file, but when I run it this is the error I get **cannot get zipimporter instance**. And I have not idea what it means

Comment: There should be a zlib DLL, it might work if you copy and paste it alongside the exe.